# passing query string with $stateprovider in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is the code that I am using currently:

in view:

```
<a ui-sref="restaurantDetail({ type: {{restaurant.type}} })" >{{restaurant.name}}</a>
```

In route,

```
 .state('restaurantDetail', {
    url: '/restaurantDetail/:type',
    templateUrl: 'templates/restaurantDetail.html',
    controller : 'restaurantDetailCtrl'
  })
```

In controller:

```
.controller('restaurantDetailCtrl', function($scope,$http,Base_URL,$state, $stateParams) {   
  console.log($stateParams); //returns Object type:""
  console.log($stateParams.type); //returns undefined
});
```

It should generate the URL `restaurantDetail/type` but it is returning `restaurantDetail`

I don't know where the issue is? I just need to pass the variable within url using `$stateProvider`

Answer (score 1):

[It should be](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)

```
restaurantDetail({ type: restaurant.type })
```

Comment: Thanks for replying,It didn't return me the resturant.type

Comment: Here is the solution that works for me, hope it help others too.

`.state('menu.restaurantDetail', {
    url: '/restaurantDetail/:type',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/restaurantDetail.html',
        controller: 'restaurantDetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })`

and the anchor tag is 

`<a ui-sref="menu.restaurantDetail({ type: restaurant.type })">{{restaurant.name}}</a>`

Answer (score 0):

AS you are not passing data correctly it should be in this way

```
<a ui-sref="restaurantDetail({ type: restaurant.type })">{{restaurant.name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Here is the code:

In route:

```
.state('menu.restaurantDetail', {
    url: '/restaurantDetail/:num',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/restaurantDetail.html',
        controller: 'restaurantDetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

in View:

```
<a ui-sref="menu.restaurantDetail({ num: restaurant.num })">{{restaurant.name}}</a>
```

Then In controller you can use `$stateParams`

```
console.log($stateParams.num);
```